# Quadratic Function problems

Tags: functions

I was attempting this problem and I am unclear where I went wrong

> A window has the shape of a rectangle surmounted by a semi circle.
> The perimeter of the window is $p$ m, where p is a positive constant. Let width of window to be $x$ m
> Supposed length of rectangle is $h$m, express h in terms of p and x and express the area $A(x)$ as a quadratic function of $x$

These are my workings:

Perimeter, $p = 2x + 2h + 0.5 π (0.5h) $

Simplifying it to: $ p = 2x + 1.25 πh$

Therefore $ h = 0.8 (p-2x) $

For the Area as a function of $x$, I am unclear as I cannot form a quadratic equation of $x$

Area (Rectangle) = $x . h$

Area (semicircle) = $ 0.125 πh^2$

I cannot form $A(x)$ as a quadratic function of $x$

Comment: why are you adding $x$ twice when you calculate the perimeter?

Comment: The perimeter doe not have a straight side on top and the diameter of the semicircle is the width, $x$, not the height $h$. So $P= x + 2h + \frac 12 \pi x$.  And the area is $x\cdot h  + (\frac 12 x)^2\pi$.  I assume we are supposed to treat $h$ as a constant.  Kind of weirdly written as $h$ is not a constant but a completely free variable.

Comment: Oops... I see.  $p$ is considered the constant.  So solve $h$ in terms of $p$ and $x$ and express the area as a quadratic function in terms of variable $x$ and constant $p$.

Comment: "I cannot form A(x) as a quadratic function of x"  well, without correctly your error.  $x\cdot h = x\cdot 0.8(p-2x) = 0.8px -1.6x^2$  (BTW.  WHY do novice students insist on using decimals instead of fractions?) And the area of the semicirce is $0.125\pi h^2 = 0.125\pi(0.8(p-2x))^2$ so $A(x) = 0.8px -1.6x^2+0.125\pi(0.8(p-2x))^2$.  (but you will have to correct your errors as I mentioned above (and do yourself a favor-- use *fractions*)